# What are intents in Python?

Tags: python

Recently I have been learning how to make a discord bot and for some reason I get this error message:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#', intents = intents)
NameError: name 'intents' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#', intents = intents)
intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server')
```

Comment: Okay. What is your *question*?

Comment: define intents before using it (swap the two lines right after import)

Comment: `intents = intents` this `intents` variable is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intents` variable is defined later so change it like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#', intents = intents)
```